# Cannot pass value to a controller function codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

here is my code of the controller

```
 public function create($postdate)
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
      //  $postdate = $this->uri->segment(3);
        echo $postdate;



        $data['title'] = 'Hey there!';


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/create',);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
        else
        {   
            $this->news_model->set_news($postdate = 20160824);
            $this->load->view('pages/success');
        }
}
```

here is my code of the model :

```
public function set_news($postdate)
{
$this->load->helper('url');


$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
$data = array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'slug' => $slug,
    'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
    'room_date' => $postdate

);

return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
}
```

but the model is not inserting the value $postdate to database.It is inserting the default value that is 20160824 where as the echo in controller is showing the  value which is passed as parameter,i.e. the (correct) value i want to insert in the database.

Comment: datatype of column room_date is?

Comment: I am a newbie in codeignitor and hence i was submitting the form to create() itself.that caused the problem.solved .!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't give default values in a function call. Rather you provide default values in the function's definition.

[SanketR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3079531/sanketr) has correctly answered your question. I would like to make it clear.

In you controller:

You are changing the value of `$postdate` to `20160824`. This is not the expected behaviour.
change this:

`$this->news_model->set_news($postdate = 20160824);`

to

`$this->news_model->set_news($postdate);`

And in your model, change the function head to:

`public function set_news($postdate = 20160824)`

This would set a default value for `$postdate` if that variable is not provided in the function call in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. The correct way would be

```
public function set_news($postdate = 20160824)
{
$this->load->helper('url');


$slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);
$data = array(
    'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
    'slug' => $slug,
    'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
    'room_date' => $postdate

);

return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
}
```

And in your controller

`$this->news_model->set_news($postdate);`

Comment: A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1048

Column 'room_date' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `news` (`title`, `slug`, `text`, `room_date`) VALUES ('just for fun', 'just-for-fun', 'lijo', NULL)

Filename: C:/wamp/www/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691

Comment: It means you are not receiving the value of `$postdate` inside your controller. Can you check it?

Comment: when im echoing inside the controller it echoes the right value